# Calling a function coming from props [React]

Tags: reactjs

I have a component `AlertError` which displays a message coming from props and I want `onClick` on this message to call a function coming from props too,

This function called is different according to the parent components of `AlertError`,

I succeeded to display the message, but the function is not executed,

I show you a small recreated example to ask you what's wrong in this,

Component 1

```
function Component1() {
  function one() {
    console.log("one");
  }
  
  return <AlertError message="one" function={() => one()} />
}
```

Component 2

```
function Component2() {
  function two() {
    console.log("two");
  }
  
  return <AlertError message="two" function={() => two()} />
}
```

Component AlertError

```
function AlertError() {
  return <div onClick={props.function}>{props.message}</div>
}
```

Comment: Can you please create a Stackblitz or Codepen for this? I don't think of any problem in your code?

Comment: Here is a working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-h3f8e9?file=src%2FApp.js

Comment: an aswer below corrected this, my file wasn't saved and I forgot to pass props as parameters of AlertError, thanks for your time spent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the props

```
function AlertError(props) {  //<--- props here
  return <div onClick={props.function}>{props.message}</div>
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-monad-isuqf?file=/src/App.js

Comment: it's working in codesandbox. Maybe you are doing something that is not reflected in the code you provided?

Comment: ok sorry my file was not saved, the ```props``` was not effective. I will mark your answer as accepted. What a shame lol

Answer (score 0):

```
<div role='button' onClick={props.function}>{props.message}</div>
```

add div role as a button

Comment: the function is still not called, ```role="button"``` is supposed to call it ?

Comment: the role is not mandatory although it's working with me